# Proving an identity using formal power series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

> 4.
>
> (a) Prove that $\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^3}=\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{1-x}}$.
>
> (b) By expanding each side of the identity in (a) as a power series, and considering the coefficient of $x^N$, prove that
>   $$\left|\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^{k}{N-k-1 \choose N-2k}\right|=\begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{ if }N\equiv1\pmod3\\
> 1 & \text{ otherwise }
> \end{cases}$$

Apparently I need to use formal power series. However, I can't seem to derive anything useful by attempting to divide $\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^3}$. How should I proceed? More generally, how should I go about proving identities using formal power series, and how should I expand a fraction into a power series?

Answer (score 3):

As DonAntonio points out, the first part is just a matter of factoring and doing some algebra. For the second part, note first that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^3}&=(1-x^2)\cdot\frac1{1-(-x^3)}\\
&=(1-x^2)\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{3n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{3n}-\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{3n+2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

in which the coefficient of $x^{3n}$ is $(-1)^n$, the coefficient of $x^{3n+1}$ is $0$, and the coefficient of $x^{3n+2}$ is $(-1)^{n+1}$. Clearly, then, the absolute value of the coefficient of $x^N$ is $0$ if $N\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $1$ otherwise.

Similarly,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{1-x}}&=\frac1{1-\left(-\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{2n}\frac1{(1-x)^n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{2n}\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}kx^k\;,\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

where the last step uses the standard power series expansion of $\dfrac1{(1-x)^n}$.

The coefficient of $x^N$ in $(1)$ is

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n\binom{N-n-1}{N-2n}\;;$$

to get this I simply write $N=2n+k$ and sum over $n$, so that $k=N-2n$. (The binomial coefficient is $0$ when $n$ is too large, so there’s no need to specify an upper bound.)

The result is now immediate.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, $$ \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x^2}{1 - x}} = \frac{1 - x}{1 - x + x^2} = \frac{(1 + x)(1 - x)}{(1 + x)\left(1 - x + x^2\right)} = \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^3} $$

For the second, consider the Maclaurin Series of $ \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^3} $ which is $$ \left( 1 - x^2\right)\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(-x^3\right)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ where $$ a_n = \begin{cases} &0 & x \equiv 1 \mod 3 \\ -&1 & x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \vee x \equiv 3 \mod 6 \\ &1 &x \equiv 5 \mod 6 \vee x \equiv 0 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$

Meanwhile, he Maclaurin Series for $ \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x^2}{1 - x}} $ is $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^\infty f(n) x^n $ where $$ f(n) := \sum_{k\ge 0 } (-1)^k  \dbinom{n -k -1}{n - 2k} $$Because the two functions are equivalent near $ x = 0 $, their Maclaurin series are the same and the equality follows.

The hard part is proving that definition of $ f(n) $. It involves expanding $ \frac{x^2}{1 - x} $ as its own Maclaurin series and then using a geometric series on $ \frac{1}{1 - \left(-\frac{x^2}{1 - x}\right)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$$

$$1+x^3=(1+x)(1-x+x^2)\;\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

To your question, “How should I expand a fraction into a power series?”, the hand-computational answer is this. You write numerator and denominator down with powers *ascending to the right* and then proceed exactly as you did in high school when you divided one polynomial into another.